# Material UI controlled expansion panel not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been having some trouble getting the Material-UI expansion panels on my React application to expand once the "expand more" icon has been clicked. I have used the documentation on the Material UI website and set up the react application using npx create-react-app. Below I have attached the code of my component and my package.json. The website displays the panel with the correctly mapped data, but the panel does not expand once clicked. Through some research I read that the latest MacOS update has been having some bugs with css frameworks and animation. Has anyone else experienced this issue? I'm not sure at this point what is causing the error.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnNhu.png)

[component imports and styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXoUV.png)

[website display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQQRJ.png)

[component render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BREgc.png)

Comment: Please include the code in your question (not images of your code).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the `onClick` props in `<ExpansionPanel />` for `onChange`.
But i have a problem like